# C++ operator[] overloading with N-Dimensional Array

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading

I'm currently working on reviewing C++ class, and while coding on operator[] overloading using N-dimensional array problem, Somehow I'm stuck right now...

IDEA : Make a 1-dim array, with total size (dim1_len * dim2_len * dim3_len ... *dimN_len) and access each element using int wrapper class.

Here's how I did:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace MyArray {
    class Array;
    class Int;

    class Array {
        friend Int;

        const int dim;
        int* size;
        int* sum_size;

        struct Address {
            int level;
            int* data;
        };

        Address* top;

        public: 
        Array(int _dim, int* _size) : dim(_dim) {
            size = new int[dim];
        
            for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) 
                size[i] = _size[i];

            top = new Address;
            top->level = 0;
        
            initialize_sum_size();
            initialize_address(top);
        }

        Array(const Array& arr) : dim(arr.dim) {
            size = new int[dim];

            for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) 
                size[i] = arr.size[i];

            top = new Address;
            top->level = 0;

            initialize_sum_size();
            initialize_address(top);

            copy_address(top, arr.top);
        }

        void initialize_address(Address* top) {
            top->data = new int[sum_size[0] * size[0]];
        }

        void copy_address(Address* dst, Address* src) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sum_size[0] * size[0]; i++) 
                dst->data[i] = src->data[i];
        }

        void initialize_sum_size() {
            sum_size = new int[dim];

            int total_length = 1;
 
            for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
                total_length *= size[i];

            for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
                total_length /= size[i];
                sum_size[i] = total_length;
            }
        }

        Int operator[](const int index);
    
        ~Array() {
            delete[] size;
            delete[] sum_size;
            delete[] top->data;
            delete top;
        }
    }; // class Array

    // Int : int wrapper class
    class Int {
        void* data_Int;
        int level;
        Array* array;

        public:
        Int(int index, int _level = -1, void* _data = NULL, Array* _array = NULL)
        : level(_level), data_Int(_data), array(_array) {
            if (_level < 0 || index >= array->size[_level]) {
                data_Int = NULL;
                return;
            }

            data_Int = static_cast<void*>(static_cast<int*>(static_cast<Array::Address*>(data_Int)->data) +
            array->sum_size[level] * index);
        }

        Int(const Int& i) : data_Int(i.data_Int), level(i.level), array(i.array) {}

        operator int() {
            if (data_Int) 
                return *static_cast<int*>(data_Int);
            return 0;
        }

        Int& operator=(const int& a) {
            if (data_Int) 
                *static_cast<int*>(data_Int) = a;
        
            return *this;
        }

        Int operator[](const int index) {
            if (!data_Int) 
                return 0;

            return Int(index, level + 1, data_Int, array);
        }
    }; // class Int

    Int Array::operator[](const int index) {
        return Int(index, 0, static_cast<void*>(top), this);
    }
}  // namespace MyArray
```

And I tested my code with this :

```
int size[] = { 2, 3, 4 };
MyArray::Array arr(3, size);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            arr[i][j][k] = (i + 1) * (j + 1) * (k + 1) + arr[i][j][k];
        }
    }
```

While going through each [], it returns "Access Violation Exception" at third loop of operator[], but not crashing at first and second loop.

```
data_Int = static_cast<void*>(static_cast<int*>(static_cast<Array::Address*>(data_Int)->data) +
                array->sum_size[level] * index);
```

And this is the line that gives me exception. I thought since initial index is `arr[0][0][0]`, it won't give me any index out of bounds error, so I don't exactly understand what went wrong in this case.

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: With the  amount of recursion going on there, you're going to need to step through your code with a debugger, and check that values are valid.   Bear in mind that an access violation is always detected AFTER the fact - in other words, the cause may be any line of code executed BEFORE the line where the exception is reported.

Comment: Casting `Address`s to `void*` and back looks like a source of unforced errors. I'd have to rewrite the code without it, but I think it's unnecessary, not sold on the need for `Address`  either, and hiding what would otherwise be an obvious mistake the compiler could have trapped for you.

Comment: Apologies for being a d**k. If the problem was obvious, you wouldn't have written the code like this. The initial structure provided is an `Address`, but after the first call `data_Int` is a pointer to a location inside the `Address`'s `data` member, and that is NOT an `Address`. When you `static_cast<Array::Address*>(data_Int)`, there isn't a valid `data` member to access, so what you get is a pointer to an unknown location in storage. In your case the pointer refers to unowned storage the third dimension tries to access resulting in the crash.

Comment: Having a 1D block of memory is the right idea. Having a proxy object that represents each dimension is the right idea (or a right idea at any rate), but all that proxy needs is a non-owned pointer to `int` (template if you want to. Don't use `void *` for type erasure because the compiler can't catch it if you screw up) to the block of data it represents, not a separate class. `Int ` already knows the rest of the information it needs.

Comment: Side note: A lot of this would be easier with `std::vector` instead of raw arrays. No need for special destructor, copy constructor and assignment operator, for one thing.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you mate, God Bless You! Thanks to you, I finally figured out what was wrong, I changed data type to int* and it worked :)

Comment: You're welcome. You may run into problems later with the = operator because it allows deviant behaviour like `arr[i][j] = 0;` To avoid this you need to have another variant of `Int` that is a leaf, and only the leaf allows assignment. Also watch out at `arr[i][j][k] = (i + 1) * (j + 1) * (k + 1) + arr[i][j][k]` in the test because it's adding to a value that hasn't been assigned a value yet. If you find the program's printing nonsense numbers, this will be why.

Comment: Side note: I usually implement access with the `()` operator and a `std::initializer_list` instead of the `[]` operator and proxies. It looks a bit weird, eg `arr({i,j,k})`, but it's a lot easier to write.